# Installing libgcrypt11-dev through Terminal on macOS

Tags: macos, ubuntu, gcc, libgcrypt

I have a project using headers such as malloc and gcrypt. To get the project to compile on my Ubuntu machine, I just have to run: `% sudo apt-get install libgcrypt11-dev`
However, I would like to be able to work on this project on my mac. I have tried to use brew for libgcrypt11-dev, but that is not a viable library with brew. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to install the equivalent of libgcrypt11-dev on macOS? I am using GCC on both machines.

Comment: If you mean this https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Libgcrypt it is `brew install libgcrypt`

Comment: I did find gcrypt, but my program still says that `#include <malloc.h>` does not exist. I am not sure which brew library malloc is in.

Comment: Ok, so what command are you using to try and compile your program? And please provide the simplest possible, complete program that doesn't work.